# Selection of Competing Exposures in a DAG: How many to use?

Tags: causality, dag, causal-diagram, backdoor-path

I am trying to get my head around when and how to include Competing Exposures in DAGs. In my searching I keep finding statements that are very similar to the quote from the dagitty tutorials - "Including competing exposures in a regression model does not affect bias, but should improve precision."

In my example below, Y is a descendant of A, B, C, X, and Z. My focus is the effect of X on Y. The adjustment sets tell me I need to close the back door by conditioning on Z, or `Y ~ X + Z`. This makes sense.

[image: DAG with competing exposured]

But, if including competing exposures improves (or "*may*" improve) precision, then I would want my model to be `Y ~ X + Z + A + B + C`. However, this quickly starts to feel like I am ignoring the principles of causal inference entirely and just throwing tons of variables into the model.

I should point out that, in my knowledge of this system, there are no pathways between A, B, & C, or any other variables.

Is there any rule or rule of thumb regarding how many competing exposures to include or not include in a model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These questions have been discussed in detail in this [recent paper](https://trialsjournal.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13063-022-06097-z). It is focused on RCTs but the same issues I believe apply (X is effectively randomised conditional on Z in your study). In short, you should adjust for prognostic covariates on grounds of efficiency. But beware the change in interpretation this might imply for non-collapsible effect measures (odds ratios, hazard ratios).

This agrees with the perspective of [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30840181/) which comes from a more distinctly causal inference perspective. Quoting from the abstract:

> Based on recent theoretically justified developments in the causal inference literature, the following proposal is made for covariate control decisions: control for each covariate that is a cause of the exposure, or of the outcome, or of both; exclude from this set any variable known to be an instrumental variable; and include as a covariate any proxy for an unmeasured variable that is a common cause of both the exposure and the outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer `@Lachlan`. As a biologist, I'm still learning the disease literature ('prognostic' isn't in my regular vocab). To be clear, in my example above, I would want to include A, B, and C in my model as long as I am confident that they are indeed influencing my outcome, even if they are not proxies for unmeasured variables that affect exposure(s) and outcome. 
Also, could you explain what "grounds of efficiency" means?

Comment: @jnat ahh yes, I shouldn't assume everyone comes from a medical field! As for adjusting for A, B, and C, yes, that's the conclusion I would reach. And by 'grounds of efficiency' I'm saying that, as you mention in the question, you will have better power/precision if you include those 'prognostic' variables in your model.